# Count instances of value from one column in another column located in another table

Tags: join, count

Let's say I have the following tables :

#### Table 1

```
task | date 
100  | 2016-01-01
101  | 2016-01-01
103  | 2016-01-01
```

#### Table 2

```
task2 | date 
113   | 2016-01-01
113   | 2016-01-01
103   | 2016-01-01
```

I would like to get to this result:

```
task_result | Count
100         | 0
101         | 0
103         | 1
```

Basically count data included in task1 table1 present in task2 table2.

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this:

```
SELECT Table1.Task, COUNT(Table2.Task)
FROM Table1
LEFT JOIN Table2
    ON Table1.Task = Table2.Task
GROUP BY Table1.Task ;
```

`Table1` is your base set, so join to it. You want to retain all values, so you use a `LEFT JOIN` and you join on the matching task values. The group and count operations happen on different columns - the `GROUP BY` is based on your tasks from `Table1`, and you `COUNT` the of tasks from `Table2`.

Here's a demo (using `CTEs` as implemented by SQL Server, PostgreSQL, Oracle, etc.):

```
WITH Table1 AS
(
    SELECT 100 AS Task
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 101
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 103
)
,Table2 AS
(
    SELECT 113 AS Task
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 113
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 103
)

SELECT Table1.Task, COUNT(Table2.Task)
FROM Table1
LEFT JOIN Table2
    ON Table1.Task = Table2.Task
GROUP BY Table1.Task ;
```